# How to subset assign values in a list of data.frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset, lapply

I have a list of data.frames, and I want to conditionally reassign values in the data.frame. If I were just assigning to a single data.frame I would say something like

```
DF[DF==9] <- NA
```

to set all entries in the data.frame that are 9 to NA. However, when I try to use `lapply` to do this same procedure on each data.frame in a list:

```
List_of_DFs <- list(DF1, DF2, DF3)
List_of_DFs <- lapply(List_of_DFs, function(x) x[x==9] <- NA)
```

Instead of each value of 9 becoming NA, the entire list entry becomes NA. So in the case above, `List_of_DFs` becomes `NA,NA,NA`.

I know I can do this with a `for` loop and the `[[]]` subsetting operator, but I figure there must be a better method.

If it's interesting or relevant, the motivation behind this problem is the list of data.frames is from XLConnect, and I will subsequently bind the data.frames by row, but I first want to drop some character values in a column that should be all numeric, so I can coerce to numeric, and subsequently bind by row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to return `x` to get the data.frame

```
lapply(List_of_DFs, function(x) {x[x==9] <- NA; x})
```

Or another option is `replace`

```
lapply(List_of_DFs, function(x) replace(x, x == 9, NA))
```

---

If we are using `dplyr` with `mutate_each` we can change the column values that are 9 to NA

```
lapply(List_of_DFs, function(x) x %>%
                                  mutate_each(funs(replace(., .==9, NA))))
```